# Selecting wifi adapter on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I have two wireless networks at home, 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz. Since my network connection is very fast, I prefer to use the 5 GHz one. However, I have a built in wireless adapter which is 2.4 GHz and a USB dongle which is 5 GHz. For some reason Windows insists on using the 2.4 GHz adapter to connect to wifi and I cannot get it to display the networks from the 5 GHz adapter in the list. I tried to change the metric in the advanced settings of the adapters but that didn't help. How can I tell Windows that I want it to use Wireless Network Adapter 2?

Comment: Disable the onboard adapter?

Comment: Tried that. It disables all WiFi adapters at the same time when you click disable.

Comment: That shouldn't happen, how are you disabling it?  Normally you'd disable a device via the Device Manager...

Comment: Ah, I went to the device in networking settings, right click then click disable. I guess I should have done it in device manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metric won't help you as it prioritizes *established* connections. Quick and dirty fix (if you usually don't need your built in adapter): Disable the adapter altogether.